# Translate ball according to the position of the bat it hits on in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
//when bat touches the ball

    ballDirection = { x: 1, y: -1 }
    document.getElementById("ball").style.transform = document.getElementById("ball").style.transform + `translate(${20 * ballDirection.x}px, ${20 * ballDirection.y}px)`;
```

Above is my code for when bat touches the ball, I want the ball to move at an angle depending on where it hit the bat. But it's not working.

https://codepen.io/pelko/pen/MWBpNmL

Currently, it moves at an angle, but the output looks weird. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: You have an inconsistency in `20 *`: sometimes you have it, sometimes you don't. It would make sense to avoid this code repetition, and only have `translate` applied in one function, so that inconsistency is not possible.

Comment: @trincot any way to fix the issue?

Comment: Eh, yes, make it consistent? (So always `20 *`)

Comment: I see why the suggested solution didn't work for you. You actually want to change the *angle* at which the ball bounces after touching the bat / paddle, right? If that's the case, I guess you would need to register the actual touching point between the two, and decide on the angle based on that. Here's an example including the angles: https://jsfiddle.net/kteuvdrn/1/ (not my creation) - take a look at how the position is handled based on the angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should probably be something like:

```
// when bat touches the ball

    ballDirection = { x: ballDirection.x, y: -ballDirection.y }
    document.getElementById("ball").style.transform = document.getElementById("ball").style.transform + `translate(${20 * ballDirection.x}px, ${20 * ballDirection.y}px)`;
```

I haven't looked closer at the rest of the code but it seems like the `ballDirection` calculated here is not kept after the encounter with the bat. There are probably some scope-related issues here to take care of.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. However, This didn't fix the issue.

Comment: @zeeshanseikh It's just a typo - it should be `ballDirection.x` and `ballDirection.y`. CarstenMassmann's solution works, you just have to correct the typo in the `ballDirection` value setting.

Comment: Did  it worked for you? It didn't work for me. @FiddlingAway